# PreparedStatement for reading temporary parameter

Tags: java, mysql, prepared-statement

I am trying to read a temporary variable created from my MySql query as follows:

```
String name = "";
                            selectQuery = "select (select "
                                    + "CONCAT(s.firstname,\" \",s.surname) "
                                    + "AS name) "
                                    + "from student s, marks m where m.grade = 'fail'";
                            try{
                                pstmt = con.prepareStatement(selectQuery);

                                rs = pstmt.executeQuery(selectQuery);
                                int count = 0;

                                while(rs.next()){
                                    name = rs.getString("name");
                                    System.out.println(++count+". "+name);
                                }
                                rs.close();
                                pstmt.close();
                            }catch(Exception e){
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
```

I get SQLException as column 'name' not found. When I run the query in MySql server it runs fine.

Comment: Too many problems to answer.  Fix your query, it is superfluous and also appears to be lacking a join condition.  Use modern join syntax, and also bind your parameters to the query in Java.

Comment: The query in the question could not possibly have been executed without an error within mysql. There is an extra select + opening parentheses at the beginning, which would cause a syntax error. And then there is no join condition, just as @TimBiegeleisen remarked.

Comment: @Shadow Then maybe the code posted isn't even what was actually run :-( ... anyway I'm gone a long time ago

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for the alias to apply, it must be places **outside** the nested query's parenthesis, not inside it. However, you could just drop it altogether and just use the `concat` call directly in the select list.

Two more side notes:

1. Implicit joins (i.e., placing more than one table in the `from` list) have been deprecated for quite a while. It's considered a better practice to use **explicit** joins.
2. Regardless of the joining syntax you're using, you're missing the join condition.
3. Using [`concat_ws`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws) instead of `concat` may save you some hassle with handling the white space yourself.

To make a long story short:

```
select CONCAT_WS(' ', s.firstname, s.surname) AS name
FROM   student s
JOIN   marks m ON s.id = m.student_id
WHERE  m.grade = 'fail'
```